# Gitlab-ci.yml to create merge reqeust

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I have the following gitlab-ci.yml file running in DEV branch, with target as DEV as well.  Since i couldnt point the TARGET as MASTER, there is no automatic MR getting created.  I would like to know if its possible to create a merge request in the gitlab-ci script itself.

```
dev:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - url_host=`git remote get-url origin | sed -e "s/https:\/\/gitlab-ci-token:.*@//g"`
    - git remote set-url origin "https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_TAG_UPLOAD_TOKEN}@${url_host}"
    - databricks workspace export_dir -o /mynotebooks.
    - git add .
    - git commit -m 'Add notebooks to Repo' -a || true
    - git push origin HEAD:dev
  tags:
    - test
```

I have searched and referred my websites, but couldnt see any notes about programmatically creating Merge Requests.

The idea is various developers are working on a databrick cluster, and gitlab is scheduled to run at regular intervals.  The changes would be pushed to DEV branch and will be pushed to MASTER branch using the Merge requests.

I would like to know if this MR creation can be automated.  NEW TO GITLAB please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create a MR in Gitlab using git push options.

To create a MR to merge `dev` into `master` using git, run the following command

```
git push origin HEAD:dev -o merge_request.create -o merge_request.target=master
```

Read more about Gitlab's [push options for merge requests](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/push_options.html).

Comment: Thanks Murli, now am able to create MR from the script. I just added another paramter, merge_when_pipeline_succeeds, so i get MRs only if the pipeline is success

Answer (score -1):

There is actually a better programable way to create MR.

Gitlab has its official [Gitlab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/) you can access to create/update/delete almost anything. Of course doing those HTTP requests by yourself will be tedious. Try use the [python library for gitlab](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-usage.html)  to do what you want. You can literally make anything programmable!

Specifically to deal with MR, you can look at [this chapter](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/merge_requests.html).